# find a column value in other columns in a pandas dataframe with apply?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a `df` that has the following form:

```
        id  Tg n0  n1  n2
fddef72025   W  A   B   C
fddef72025   A  A   B   C
fddef72025   Y  A   B   C
fddef72025   B  A   B   C
```

I need to create a new column and store a 1 if `Tg` is in either `df.n0`, `df.n1` or `df.n2`, so for example for the `df` above:

```
        id  Tg n0  n1  n2  exists
fddef72025   W  A   B   C       0
fddef72025   A  A   B   C       1
fddef72025   Y  A   B   C       0
fddef72025   B  A   B   C       1
```

My solution so far involves "iterrows", but I'm sure there is a way to `df.apply` this?

Comment: This can be done with `np.where`, are you looking for a solution or a solution that only uses pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think check `df.eq` against `df.Tg` on `axis=0` will give your desired ouput

```
df['exist'] = df[['n0', 'n1', 'n2']].eq(df.Tg, axis=0).any(1).astype(int)

Out[204]:
           id Tg n0 n1 n2  exist
0  fddef72025  W  A  B  C      0
1  fddef72025  A  A  B  C      1
2  fddef72025  Y  A  B  C      0
3  fddef72025  B  A  B  C      1
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC

```
df.loc[:,'n0':].isin(df.Tg).any(1).astype(int)
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: good one! I completely forgot that `df.isin` against series is matching on both value and index :) +1